# Access 2010 VBA - Dialogue box that opens when query starts, closes when query is done

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a query that takes a bit of time to complete. My users don't realize that a query is taking place once they click a button, seeing as there isn't a dialogue box or text explaining what steps the process is on. My question is:

`Is it possible to create a dialogue box that appears when a query begins, and closes when a query ends?`

If it's possible to update the dialogue box (i.e. when my first subform is being updated, have the box say `Updating User information` and when my second subform is being updated it says 
`Calculating Monthly Suggestions`) in VBA. I am using this in my Access 2010 database.

TIA!

Comment: for another idea see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459734/using-msgbox-without-pausing-the-application

Comment: @pony2deer excellent link, just what I was looking for! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

although pony2deer's link offers the Application.StatusBar solution.. I've found the status bar doesn't attract the user's attention and often goes entirely unnoticed.

I'd recommend using a form that shows just before the query is executed, then hides just after the query finishes running. If you already have a form open (sounds like you do), you can simply add a label to the form and update the caption.  Update it to #1 below right before the query is executed.  Then update it again to #2 right after the query finishes processing.

1.) labelStatus.Caption = "Please wait while your query is processed..."

2.) labelStatus.Caption = "Success! Your query has finished processing."

Jack up the font size, make it colorful, etc.  You really want the status to jump out so your users don't go around clicking things and impacting the performance of your app.

Comment: I agreed that the Status Bar was very unnoticeable. So much so that I didn't even realize it had text displaying on it until I was suggested to use it . I actually went with this route anyway, so I'll accept yours as the answer. Thanks!